# In Skyrim, what does a full armor set entail?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

I.E., do I have to have a shield, or can I just have the helmet, armor, gauntlets, and boots?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

A full armor set is simply is entirely based on around worn pieces, such as helmet, armor, gauntlets, boots, etc. Shields are considered separate pieces of armor, hence why they are placed within the "Block" skill and not the "Heavy/Light Armor" skills.

Comment: this doesn't really answer my question though.  You said shields are considered to be armor, so does that mean that I have to have it equipped to get a full set bonus?  I have the Dawngaurd DLC, and my Dawngaurd armor says that it will give me a bonus if I wear a full set of Dawngaurd armor.  Do I have to use the Dawngaurd shield, or does it work without it?

Comment: @Horus It answers your question: "A full armor set is simply is entirely based on around worn pieces, such as helmet, armor, gauntlets, boots". No, you don't need the shield.